# How to downgrade visual studio specflow extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, specflow

Recently the Specflow extension in my visual studio 2015 got upgraded automatically because of which I am facing many issues. I see no options to revert it to the previous version.

Comment: You will probably need to uninstall the extension and download the specific version of the extension you want, and install it manually.